# How to access http response headers

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="something"></script>

<img src="something">


<script>
window.onload = function () {

//code logic here

}
</script>
</body>
</html>


I want to access the http response headers for all the http requests of this page so that I can determine their status.
```

such as response header for first script request and others subsequently.

In other words I want to count the no. of requests for which the response status was an error.

Comment: Have you considered just using something like Fiddler?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```

Comment: This will only give me response header for the document not all the response headers for all the requests.

Comment: all the response headers for all the requests??

Comment: <script src="something"> also makes a request I want to know what was the response for such requests as well.

Comment: How about keeping this code in a function and calling it in places where you want to get the response?